# What "Star Wars" comic featured a character using the old "Battlestar Galactica" laser pistol?

Tags: star-wars, comics, episode-identification, battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-1978

What I know:

This was a current-canon comic (so published within the last 7-ish years.) I saw pictures/panels/illustrations from it on Wookieepedia within the last six months (so it might be an especially recent publication) and noted that a character was carrying the Colonial Warrior laser pistol from the original *Battlestar Galactica* TV show. I've since forgotten who the character was and didn't pay attention to the rest of the article.

What I think:

It was a female character. Possibly a bounty hunter or a smuggler. Possibly a Rebel. Pretty sure it was a human, but I am not fully certain.

What the blaster/laser pistol looks like:

[image: futuristic pistol with red spots]

[image: same pistol seen from a different angle]

Answer (score 1):

Could it be this panel of Sana Starros from *Star Wars (2015)* #6?

[image: Panel from Star Wars comic showing Sana Starros pointing a blaster at Han and Leia]

(source: crop from https://www.starwars.com/news/who-is-sana-starros)

[image: Close-up of blaster] [image: Close-up of colonial blaster from BSG]

It's not a perfect match, since other angles show that she's using a two-handed [EE-4 carbine rifle](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/EE-4_carbine_rifle):
[image: Comic panel showing Sana Starros holding a blaster rifle]

...but the first panel would be easy to mistake for a one-handed pistol that looks a lot like the *Battlestar Galactica* prop, and the character description fits (female, human, scoundrel, later hired by the Rebels). The image can also be found on [her Wookieepedia article](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sana_Starros#Personality_and_traits), which could be where you saw it.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. I remember it being a side-view of the pistol and unmistakably the BSG one. I've looked again off and on since I posted the question and still haven't found it.